# Tensorflow, Reshape like a convolution

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I have a matrix [3,3,256], my final output must be [4,2,2,256], I have to use a reshape like a 'convolution' without changing the values. (In this case using a filter 2x2). Is there a method to do this using tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to store the original values redundantly in the new structure, like this (without the last dim of 256):

```
[ [ 1 2 3 ]          [ [ 1 2 ]    [ [ 2 3 ]    [ [ 4 5 ]     [ [ 5 6 ]
  [ 4 5 6 ]       =>   [ 4 5 ] ],   [ 5 6 ] ],   [ 7 8 ] ],    [ 8 9 ] ]
  [ 7 8 9 ] ]
```

If yes, you can use indexing, like this, with `x` being the original tensor, and then stack them:

```
x2 = []
for i in xrange( 2 ):
     for j in xrange( 2 ):
         x2.append( x[ i : i + 2, j : j + 2, : ] )
y = tf.stack( x2, axis = 0 )
```

Based on your comment, if you *really* want to avoid using any loops, you might utilize the [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches), like below (tested code) but you should run some tests because this might actually be much worse than the above in terms of efficiency and perfomance:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.constant( [ [ [ 1, -1 ], [ 2, -2 ], [ 3, -3 ] ],
                   [ [ 4, -4 ], [ 5, -5 ], [ 6, -6 ] ],
                   [ [ 7, -7 ], [ 8, -8 ], [ 9, -9 ] ] ] )
xT = tf.transpose( x, perm = [ 2, 0, 1 ] ) # have to put channel dim as batch for tf.extract_image_patches
xTE = tf.expand_dims( xT, axis = -1 ) # extend dims to have fake channel dim
xP = tf.extract_image_patches( xTE, ksizes = [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ],
        strides = [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], rates = [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], padding = "VALID" )
y = tf.transpose( xP, perm = [ 3, 1, 2, 0 ] ) # move dims back to original and new dim up front

print( sess.run(y) )
```

Output (horizontal separator lines added manually for readability):

> [[[[ 1 -1]
>     [ 2 -2]]
>
> [[ 4 -4]
>     [ 5 -5]]]
>
> ---
>
> [[[ 2 -2]
>     [ 3 -3]]
>
> [[ 5 -5]
>     [ 6 -6]]]
>
> ---
>
> [[[ 4 -4]
>     [ 5 -5]]
>
> [[ 7 -7]
>     [ 8 -8]]]
>
> ---
>
> [[[ 5 -5]
>     [ 6 -6]]
>
> [[ 8 -8]
>     [ 9 -9]]]]

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I cannot use cycle for (for efficiency)

Comment: Well, it only uses a loop once at the beginning to _set up_ the network. Once it's up and you run it with `sess.run( y )` it will have been optimized by Tensorflow.

Comment: Updated my answer anyway with a loop-free version

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with you and I found that in `tf.contrib.kfac.utils` there is a function called `extract_convolution_patches`. Suppose you have a tensor `X` with shape `(1, 3, 3, 256)` where the initial 1 marks batch size, you can call

```
Y = tf.contrib.kfac.utils.extract_convolution_patches(X, (2, 2, 256, 1), padding='VALID')
Y.shape    # (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 256)
```

The first two 2's will be the number of your output filters (makes up the `4` in your description). The latter two 2's will be the shape of the filters. You can then call

```
Y = tf.reshape(Y, [4,2,2,256])
```

to get your final result.